# How to apply Devexpress Skin to devexpress textbox control?

Tags: asp.net, themes, devexpress

I used Devexpress Theme Builder in order to create a theme. I successfully applied the theme. The problem arised when I had different width aspx:textboxes. I decided to create skins in Theme Builder and only change the width. I used SkinID property to set the skin on textbox, but I don't see the effect. I registered my theme with the following code.

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
ThemeAssembly.ThemesProviderEx.Register();
```

Should I do similar registration for my skins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the SkinID on markup, the theme the skin is in also should be defined.

For example

```
<dx:aspxcombobox Theme="MyTheme" SkinID="MySkin" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Set file Web.Config themes tag with theme name dll:

> ```
> <themes enableThemesAssembly="TRUE" styleSheetTheme="" theme="ThemeAssembly" />
> <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true"
> ```
>
> enableResourceMerging="true" />